# Java: How do I get the returning value of the fastest task with a specific condition?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have three classes, let's say A, B and C.

Each of them uses a different algorithm.

In my main class Main, I want to have a method like "search(String toSearch)". That method uses the classes A, B and C.

**I want that each task (of A, B, C) has his own thread** and that my method "search" **returns the value of the "fastest task" (with a specific condition, that the returning value is NOT NULL)**. The other tasks should then immediately die, if possible (because they are not needed anymore).

Thanks in advance.

Example of what I am trying to do:

```
public static String search(String toSearch) {
    String aResult = A.search(toSearch);
    String bResult = B.search(toSearch);
    String cResult = C.search(toSearch);
    // aResult, bResult & cResult should start at the same time and the first one with a result (NOT NULL) is the "winner"
// if any of them is NULL (or empty), then we'll return NULL
    // return the first result that is NOT NULL and let the others die if they are still searching
}
```

Comment: do you actually mean the task with the lowest latency, even if it started after the other tasks? or you expect to start them at the same time and let them race?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting 3 tasks (A,B,C) to an executor service with at least 3 threads should run them in parallel.

Each task should do 2 more things, notify and check if they should stop.

Example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class FastestOf3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(search("foo"));
    }

    static Object search(String key) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        final Object[] answer = new Object[1];
        Future f1 = es.submit(() -> searchEmulation(answer, 1000, "1"));
        Future f2 = es.submit(() -> searchEmulation(answer, 200, "2"));
        Future f3 = es.submit(() -> searchEmulation(answer, 500, "3"));
        synchronized(answer) {
            while(! (f1.isDone() && f2.isDone() && f3.isDone()) && answer[0]==null) {
                answer.wait();
            }
            es.shutdownNow();
        }
        return answer[0];

    }

    static void searchEmulation(Object[] mailbox, int delay, Object answer) {
        //some work...
        if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            return;
        //some more work...
        if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            return;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        //some more work...
        synchronized(mailbox) {
            if(mailbox[0]==null)
                mailbox[0] = answer;
            mailbox.notify(); //notify even if no result, to wake main thread to check.
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: THIS! Thank you ;) Btw, as I am curious: Is there a better way (performance, style) than this one?

Comment: Performance? I don`t see much issue here. It would be premature to optimize this. You need to measure a problem first. Style? Sure you can avoid the lazy coder's Object[] trick. A dedicated static inner class would probably be more suited.The hardcoding to 3 tasks is clearly a 1-off choice, to keep it simple; no one asked for a framework yet. Using interruptions is borderline acceptable because it is an interruption after all, but since I don't know what your search functions do, interrupting may be destabilizing. A periodic boolean check could be safer but may not be hard enough.

Answer (score 0):

Analizing you code.
If exists the result in  `String aResult = A.search(toSearch);` mean that is blocking. So others statments will not work until aResult receive the result.

If A.search, B.search, and C.search are concurrents then you code should be like:

```
public static String search(String toSearch) {
    //
    A.search(toSearch, observer);
    B.search(toSearch, observer);
    C.search(toSearch, observer);
    //
    return observer.get()//blocked until an result NOT NULL
}
```

The observer is something like:

```
public class Observer {
    private Object value;

    public void set(Object value){
        if (value != null) {
          syncronized(this){
            this.value = value;
            this.notify();
          }
        }
    }    

    public Object get(){
        syncronized(this){
           this.wait()
        }
        return value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for Java's ExecutorCompletionService: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html .